# Rails Group, Order and Limit in one Table Active Records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

i'm fairly new to Rails and try to implement a query for GraphQl, i want to get the 10 latest entries (by published_at) for each feed_id from my table (Entries) with one Active Record query.

My Models look like this:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :feed 

    "some methods"

end
```

```
class Feed < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My Tables looks like this:

Entries table:

| id | title | published_at | feed_id | ...... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | date1 | 1 | ...... |
| 2 | title2 | date2 | 1 | ...... |
| 3 | title3 | date3 | 2 | ...... |
| 4 | title4 | date4 | 1 | ...... |
| N | titleN | dateN | 3 | ...... |

Feed table:

| id (feed_id) | url | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | url1 | ..... |
| 2 | url2 | ..... |
| 3 | url3 | ..... |
| 4 | url4 | ..... |
| N | urlN | ..... |

I've already tried different solutions here on stackoverflow for similar problems but nothing worked out so far, so maybe someone has a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Entry.order(published_at: :desc).limit(10).group_by(&:feed_id)
```

Thanks!